# useState array changing unexpectedly React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to access a useState array, however it is changing unexpectedly to the length of the list.

For example say I had my useState array

```
const [problemSet, setProblemSet] = useState([])
```

I then add random unique numbers to the array

```
    let newProblemSet = []
    #level > 1
    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++){
      let randomCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
      if (newProblemSet.includes(randomCell)){
        i--
      } else {
        newProblemSet.push(randomCell)
      }
    }

    #add newProblemSet to my useState
    for (let i = 0; i < newProblemSet.length; i++){
      setProblemSet(problemSet.push(newProblemSet[i]))
    }

    #light up function is called where 
    lightUp()
```

I then have a button, and when clicked a console.log function is called

```
return(){
  <div>
    cellClick(1)
  </div>
}
```

**cellClick**

```
  function cellClick(c){
    console.log(problemSet)
  }
```

**output** is the length of problemSet, for example 2

### FULL CODE

```
import "./Memory.css"

import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'

import _ from "lodash";

export default function Memory(){
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false)
  const [problem, setProblem] = useState(false)
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(3)
  const [problemSet, setProblemSet] = useState([])
  const [guessSet, setGuessSet] = useState([])

  async function dim(i){
    document.getElementsByClassName("cell"+problemSet[i])[0].classList.add('dim')
    document.getElementsByClassName("cell"+problemSet[i])[0].classList.remove('light')
  }

  async function lightUp(){
    console.log("problemSet",problemSet)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    //iterate through problem set and light up according cells
    for (let i = 0; i < problemSet.length; i++){
      document.getElementsByClassName("cell"+problemSet[i])[0].classList.remove('dim')
      document.getElementsByClassName("cell"+problemSet[i])[0].classList.add('light')
      console.log("lightup NOW", problemSet)
      //wait for cells to light up then dim them
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 800));
      await dim(i)
    }
    setProblem(false)
  }


  function cellClick(c){
    console.log(problemSet)
  }


  //generate unique cell positions for problem
  if (problem){

    let newProblemSet = []
    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++){
      let randomCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
      if (newProblemSet.includes(randomCell)){
        i--
      } else {
        newProblemSet.push(randomCell)
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < newProblemSet.length; i++){
      setProblemSet(problemSet.push(newProblemSet[i]))
    }

    setProblem(false)
    lightUp()
    console.log(problemSet)
  }

  return (
    <div>
            <div className="main-container">
                <div className="title-container">
                    <h1 className="game-title">
                        Test Your Memory!
                    </h1>
                    <p className="game-subtitle"> Are you an Elephant? </p>
                </div>

                {
                        start ?

                            <div className="memory-container">
                                <div class="grid">
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(1)} className="cell1 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(2)} className="cell2 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(3)} className="cell3 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(4)} className="cell4 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(5)} className="cell5 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(6)} className="cell6 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(7)} className="cell7 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(8)} className="cell8 dim"></div>
                                  <div onClick={()=>cellClick(9)} className="cell9 dim"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        :
                            <div className="start-container">
                                <input className="start-button" type="button" value="Start Game" onClick={() => {setStart(true); setProblem(true)}}/>
                            </div>
                }
          </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.push()` method returns the new length of the array. In addition, setting the array multiple times after updating it is redundant since react would only re-render if the array is replaced and not mutated.

Just set the array after you've filled it - `setProblemSet(newProblemSet)`.

Furthermore, you shouldn't update the state as part of the render, as it might cause an unending loops of render. Move the update to a `useEffect` block:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(problem) {
    const newProblemSet = []
    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++){
      const randomCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1
      if (newProblemSet.includes(randomCell)){
        i--
      } else {
        newProblemSet.push(randomCell)
      }
    }

    setProblemSet(newProblemSet)

    setProblem(false)
  }
}, [problem])
```

You should also use the state to update the DOM and not using direct DOM methods like you do in `lightUp` and `dim`. Classes/styles changed manually via DOM methods would be resetted after each render.

Comment: Everything you said makes total sense, however now I am not able to access ProblemSet in light up. However I am able to access it in cellClick. Is this due to my asynchronous mess?

Comment: The basic problem is not setting the state correctly, the others are not setting it in `useEffect`, and changing DOM directly. You need to do some React reading before your continue. The async stuff is just a weird addition, and there are better ways to do it in React.

Answer (score 0):

10/16/2022
I am a certified MERN stack software engineer.
You can connect with me on Linkendin Eddie Teah

I gived you an example of useEffect implementation
--- it basically updates the state using 3 checks:
1: a given amount of times
2: when triggered
3: when DOM load ie: "onComponentDidMount".

I updated the syntax of your script to use ES6 arrow function and exported your script as using modules-container-object format...giving you room to export more functions.
Ex: To import Memory.js you should use import{Memory} from "urlpath"

What's Next:
I would sugget you look into Redux.
I was going to handle this state management issue with Redux
However, I figure it would not be good for note taking.
But redux can solve this problem in a flash.
Again, If you need help you can contact me or ask question here or linkendin

Heres an edited version of you script:

```
 import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

let Memory = () => {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  const [problem, setProblem] = useState(false);
  const [level, setLevel] = useState(3);
  const [problemSet, setProblemSet] = useState([]);
  let newProblemSet = [];
  const [guessSet, setGuessSet] = useState([]);

  //

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`ET: problemSet  ${problemSet}`);
    console.log(`ET: Sorry to say but...This is not deterministic  -I could solve this in two ways, one being -> state management with redux, but
    thats just too much code-apart from redux, I would also advice you catch async issues ex: try{}catch(err){console.log(err)}`);
  }, [problemSet]);

  /*
  async function dim(i) {
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cell" + problemSet[i])[0]
      .classList.add("dim");
    document
      .getElementsByClassName("cell" + problemSet[i])[0]
      .classList.remove("light");
  }

  async function lightUp() {
    console.log("problemSet", problemSet);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    //iterate through problem set and light up according cells
    for (let i = 0; i < problemSet.length; i++) {
      document
        .getElementsByClassName("cell" + problemSet[i])[0]
        .classList.remove("dim");
      document
        .getElementsByClassName("cell" + problemSet[i])[0]
        .classList.add("light");
      console.log("lightup NOW", problemSet);
      //wait for cells to light up then dim them
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 800));
      await dim(i);
    }
    setProblem(false);
  }

  function cellClick(c) {
    console.log(problemSet);
  }*/

  //generate unique cell positions for problem
  //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
  if (problem == true) {
    let randomCell = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < level; i++) {
      randomCell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
      //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
      //ET-Concern-You are increasing the loop's process by forcing i to be smaller than what it is
      //Why are you doing this?
      /*
      if (newProblemSet.includes(randomCell)) {
        i--;
      } else {
        newProblemSet.push(randomCell);
      }
      */
      //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
      if (newProblemSet.includes(randomCell) == false) {
        newProblemSet.push(randomCell);
      }
    }
    //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
    //setProblemSet( );
    /*
    for (let i = 0; i < newProblemSet; i++) {
      let element = problemSet.push(newProblemSet[i]);
      setProblemSet(element);
    }*/
    // setProblemSet(newProblemSet);
    // lightUp();
    //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
    setProblem(false);
    setProblemSet(newProblemSet);
    console.log(`newProblemSet: ${newProblemSet}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="main-container">
        <div className="title-container">
          <h1 className="game-title">Test Your Memory!</h1>
          <p className="game-subtitle"> Are you an Elephant? </p>
        </div>

        {
          //[ET Edit 10/16/22]
          //id ="I removed the class you had below-So I can test the button without a DOM error"
          start == true ? (
            <div className="memory-container">
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(1)} className="cell1 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(2)} className="cell2 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(3)} className="cell3 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(4)} className="cell4 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(5)} className="cell5 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(6)} className="cell6 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(7)} className="cell7 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(8)} className="cell8 dim"></div>
              <div onClick={() => cellClick(9)} className="cell9 dim"></div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="start-container">
              <input
                className="start-button"
                type="button"
                value="Start Game"
                onClick={() => {
                  setProblem(true);
                  setStart(true);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export { Memory };
```